# Host Cannot be null in EF migrations

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I added connection appsettings.json file

```
 "PostgreConnectionString": {
    "PostgreConnection": "host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=OpenAccessDB;user=postgres;password=postgres;Integrated Security=true;"
  }
```

program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<OpenAccessDBContext>(o => o.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreConnection")));
```

I have created migrations but i am trying to update database command in migrations getting issue like host cannot be null

I didn't understand what is the issue here. Can someone tell me what is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

Under "Solution Explorer", Right click on the "appsettings.json" and click "Properties".
Then under "Properties", change the value of "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always" or "Copy if newer".

As "update-database" would build the solution and the "GetConnectionString" would try to local the appsettings.json in output directory.